# Submit a link to Digg: Invalid URL

Tags: digg

I am trying to submit an URL to Digg, but get `Invalid URL`:

[image]

What's the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add **index.html**<sup>1</sup> to the end of your URL and then Digg should accept your submission, it worked for me.

<sup>1</sup> or index.htm, or index.asp, or default.htm, or whatever the webserver uses for the default document

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that Digg does not accept server-only URLs.

The unit at Digg is stories, not websites.
They have a filter that tries to detect whether an URL is a story or not.

So instead of `server.com`, I submitted `server.com/article.html` and it worked:

[image]